# Find a String key associated with the Max Integer value in a Map<String, Integer>

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

As a preface, very new to Java and extremely new to `HashMaps`.

I have a `HashMap` that has strings as keys and associated integer values that represent frequency. I would like to know the **most efficient** way to find the *key* associated with the max integer *value*.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public String most(String[] sentences) {

    HashMap<String, Integer> wordFreq = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for(String sentence : sentences) {
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        for (String word : words) {
            wordFreq.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
    }
    
    //TODO find key associated with max integer value in map
}
```

Comment: You could [reverse the Map](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/11-mapreverser)

Comment: @g00se There's no need to post-process the map, since the primary concern is performance. The most frequent word can be found while accumulating the values ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73625727/17949945)).

Comment: What do you want to return if you have many words with the same maximum value?

Comment: Clearly performance is not relevant for this question. If the primary concern was performance, there wouldn't be a Hashmap used to map strings to Integers in the first place, we'd be using a goal-appropriate data structure instead. So: is this just an exercise, or are you _actually_ trying to do something here? (in which case, please also talk about that, to avoid [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: "The key" is a problem. Uniqueness isn't necessary. You're either looking for a set that may contain up to all the keys or maybe an arbitrary element of that set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this.  Stream `entrySet` of the map and then get the maximum entry by using `maxBy` on the value of the entry.  Since `maxBy` returns an `Optional`, you can then use `map` to get the value. Return an informatory message if no value exists.

```
 String result  = wordFreq.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Entry.comparingByValue()))
                .map(Entry::getKey).orElse("No Value Found");
```

And as was commented on you could also do this.  I tend to use the first one out of habit.

```
String result = wordFreq.entrySet().stream()         
    .max(Entry.comparingByValue())
    .map(Entry::getKey).orElse("No Value Found");
```

You could also use other ways to optimize this but since you constructed a map I figured that is how you wanted to do it.
If you need a map of words, you may want to construct it outside of the method.  Then just pass the map to the method instead of an array of sentences.  That way you can use the map for other things.

Since you haven't yet had a chance to respond to my question, I will offer a solution regarding ties for the maximum occurrence of a word.  Similar as before except first you return the maximum value found.  The you can stream the `entrySet`, filtering for the entries that have the maximum value. Then just collect into a list.

```
int max = wordFreq.entrySet().stream()           
    .max(Entry.comparingByValue()).map(Entry::getValue)
            .orElse(0);
    
List<String> wordFreq.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() == max).map(Entry::getKey)
            .toList();
    
}
```

Lastly, you use stream constructs to create the initial frequency map.  I am using `\\s+` as the regex as there could be more than one space.  The `splitAsStream` will apply the pattern and the `toMap` is similar to a `merge` in functionality.

```
Map<String, Integer> wordFreq = Arrays.stream(sentences)
                .flatMap(s -> Pattern.compile("\\s+").splitAsStream(s))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> 1,
                        Integer::sum));
```

Answer (score 1):

The most frequent word can be found while accumulating the values of the Map. That would allow to **avoid** the overheads of iterating over the map entries.

For that, we need to introduce a couple of variables an one condition into your existing code.

Method `merge()` returns a *current value* associated with the offered *key*. Which allows to track the maximum value and update the most frequent word in the input accordingly.

```
public String most(String[] sentences) {
    
    Map<String, Integer> wordFreq = new HashMap<>();
    String most = "no data";
    int max = 0;
    
    for(String sentence : sentences) {
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        for (String word : words) {
            int current = wordFreq.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
            
            if (current > max) {
                most = word;
                max = current;
            }
        }
    }
    return most;
}
```

In case when there are multiple words having the same frequency in the input (which happens to be maximal) and you want to get all of them, the return type should be collection of strings, for instance `List<String>`. And instead of maintaining the most frequent word as a string, we need to maintain a collection of strings.

```
public List<String> most(String[] sentences) {
    
    Map<String, Integer> wordFreq = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> mostFrequent = new ArrayList<>();
    int max = 0;
    
    for(String sentence : sentences) {
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        for (String word : words) {
            int current = wordFreq.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
            
            if (current >= max) {
                if (current > max) {
                    mostFrequent = new ArrayList<>();
                    max = current;
                }
                mostFrequent.add(word);
            }
        }
    }
    return mostFrequent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you also might consider using a bi-directional map implementation like [apache commons collections BidiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html) or [guava's BiMap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap)

But as your Map values are not unique, for high performance you need some sort of index to search for a key. There are no indexes that work in both directions, so actually you need 1 Map (for key to value) and 1 Multimap (for value to keys), and a wrapper that will maintain both in consistent state on any mutation (insert, upeate, delete,...)